# Show most recent search terms in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

Is there a way to show the most recent search terms done on my site? I want to display the last 3-5 search terms done by my visitors so other users will be encouraged to search something as well.

**Edit:** In this case, refreshing the page may show a new set of search terms if someone searched something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are at least a few plugins that can help you with this.

I would recommend the [Recent Searches Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recent-searches-widget/), it's a plugin that gets a lot of good reviews. It allows you to add a widget to your sidebar (or wherever) that displays the most recent search terms used on your site. I don't believe it will display any searches that were made prior to it's activation but once it's installed and active it will track each search that's made.