# Show last search term in search field

Tags: php, html, forms, search

I need the search code below to show the very last search term displayed inside the search field. So if someone searches 'Dogs' I need 'Dogs' showing inside the form. I could give another example, but I'm sure you understand.

I already found a solution on this site here ([Show most recent search terms in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180900/show-most-recent-search-terms-in-wordpress)) but it only works on WordPress. I need a stand-a-lone version. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

```
<form class="form" action="http://example.com/?search=" target="_parent" method="get">
<input type="text" id="search" name="term" value="Search for..."/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" title="Search" id="submit"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

AlliterativeAlice is right but you also need to use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) otherwise e.g. if your search term is `I'm looking for "something"` then it will appear as `I'm looking for` in your input element so your user will get a wrong impression!

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="term" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['term'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['term']) : 'Search for...'; ?>" />
```

Comment: Sorry. It does not work. On page load the search field is populated with text that says "Search for...". I have to erase that text, then type in the term. Example: dogs - When I refresh the page after entering the search term 'dogs' the search field shows the same text inside the field "Search for...". The term 'dogs' does not show. Would I need to create a sql database and retrieve the search term that way?

Comment: You may need to change both instances of 'term' to the name of your search field input. For example, if you use the default WordPress search form, the name is 's' so you would change 'term' above to 's'. Just adding this because that's why it was coming up blank for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the input to the following should show the term if there is one or "Search for..." if there isn't.

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="term" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : 'Search for...'); ?>"/>
```